# Angular ng annotate does not work with babel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I am using browserify and babel to compile my js files and i want the ng annotate plugin too but it is not working, any ideas why?

The gulp task:

```
  browserify(config.js.src, { debug: true })
    .transform(babel.configure({ ignore: /vendor\// }))
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source(config.js.mainFileName))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js.dist));

class HomeController {
  // @ngInject
  constructor($http) {
    this.name = 'avi';
  }
}

export default HomeController;
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working", what happens instead?

Comment: its not happening, there is no $inject in the dist code.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have ng-annotate run before the browserify transform?

Answer (score 3):

I think in your case Babel is stripping comments. Ng-annotate works with compiled es5 code and have to somehow know what to annotate. You can either run babel with `comments: true` and `compact: false` to preserve comments or use string literals:

```
constructor($http) {
    "ngInject";
    this.name = 'avi';
}
```

Comment: `comments: true` is actually default.  What I discovered in my particular case is that I was converting ES6 modules to commonjs with babel, and babel was inserting a few statements between my comment and the outputted `function YourClass`, which was frustrating ng-annotate.  My solution also ended up placing `"ngInject"` literals at the top of the function.